# React className remove and add

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6zbB.png)

When clicked, I want to erase all className and add className only to the clicked value.

If you look at the picture, className is added to the value and works normally.

However, when you click another value, the className of the previously clicked value is maintained and two values are applied.

When clicked, remove className to all values and add className to the clicked value.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please post code as text, not links to images of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove use a state with the index or any identifier in the app to control to show or not your style based on this identifier.

```
className={enabled === 1 ? "back" : ""} 
onClick={() => setEnabled(1)}
```

a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-firefly-e1uqu?file=/src/App.js